# Download GRASS GIS addons and install from local machine

Tags: grass-gis, docker

I use GRASS GIS from a Docker container, and every time I rebuild the image, addons like r.stream.order and r.stream.snap are installed from the GRASS repository. Maybe it's an improper way and I should download these addons previously, then install from a local computer? Is it possible? It seems not to be correct to address every time to remote repository.
I install addons after the container is built, with a script, run as the last command of dockerfile.

UPD: The essense here is - how can I run `grass --exec sh upgrade_grass.sh` before creating LOCATION?
upgrade_grass.sh is:

```
g.extension r.stream.snap
g.extension r.stream.basins
g.extension r.stream.order
```

UPD2: seems that [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331686/creating-a-grass-gis-docker-container-with-a-mounted-volume) is some information in p.2

Comment: Upon rebuild I'd actually expect that addons are also fetched again - there might have been updates. Why is it a problem for you and unexpected?

Comment: It's not a problem. I only imagine how often grass servers are asked for fetching addons. If this way is optimal, and you are aware, and you proposed that it should be so, I don't have any problem at all and I will go on using addons that way. Thanks.